# Checking null value inside function returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, if-statement, null

I am not sure what's going on here. When I check if variable is null inside the function I get (variable is not null) which is not correct but if I remove the function part and test directly it returns (variable is null) which is correct. What's happening ? why is javascript so confusing ?

```
var variable = null;

function scoppedVariables(variable) {
  if( variable === null ) {
  console.log('variable is null');
} else {
  console.log('variable is not null');
}

}

scoppedVariables();
```

Comment: scoppedVariables() pass the value where you call the function

Comment: You're not passing anything to the function, so it has nothing to work with, null or otherwise.

Comment: I feel so stupid right now :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you accept `variable` as parameter, it takes over the `variable` which you defined outside the function.  As you don't pass it on the function call, in the function it's rather `undefined` than `null`. (You could've used the non-strict comparison, but in this case you wouldn't have figured what's actually going on ;))

Answer (score 2):

```
null == undefined // true
null === undefined // false
```

The method is called with no arguments, therefore `variable` is undefined, which is not *strictly* equal to `null`.

Either call the function with a parameter or remove it from the signature:

```
function scoppedVariables(){..}
```

When called that way, it will access the global parameter, it's a better practive to pass the variable you want to the function though.

Answer (score 0):

Amend your function to use this instead...

```
if (typeof variable == 'undefined') {
    console.log('variable is undefined');
} else {
    console.log('variable is defined');
    if (variable == null) {
        console.log('variable is null);
    } else {
        console.log('variable is not null');
    }
}
```

You were not passing anything in your function call, hence `variable` would be undefined, rather than null. You may wish to be more defensive regarding parameter inputs, as I've illustrated here.